# Use-Mention distinction with letters

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-language

When you spell a word, are you using or mentioning the letters? Also, in general, is it possible to use letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting question, but I think it mostly boils down to two definition problems occurring in tandem.

First, we need to be clear about [use-mention](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quotation/#2.2):

> Despite its ubiquitous appeal, it is controversial exactly how to draw the distinction. The initial thought is easy enough...

The SEP article then supplies an example and maintains that the baseline is something is used when it denotes a thing or person in the world and mentioned when it signifies the word.

---

It's going to be hard to apply that definition to spelling a word since spelling a word (restricting this to languages that use an alphabet or syllabary) involves letters as they relate to words.

To put it another way "Sammy" is spelled "s" "a" "m" "m" "y" seems to

mention "Sammy"
but use "s" "a" "m" "m" "y" insofar as the very use of the letters is to spell words.

but you could also argue that it merely mentions both if you see the names of the letters as distinct words from their use in spelling things.

This account assumes that by "spell" you mean to "spell out" as into consciously engage in the act of spelling a word. If you are unconsciously spelling words (not thinking about the letters but merely producing the word), then it's not clear there's any room for a use-mention distinction. I say this because I don't know how you would be mentioning anything in that case, since you are using the letters to make words which are also being used in their use rather than being mentioned.

Comment: This is a very interesting point. I did in fact mean "spell" in the sense of "spell out". It seems that something can be mentioned only if it can be used in the first place. So first there would have to be a way to use letters in the first place (I would take it that this is to spell something out). Then to mention the letters would seem to refer to what you use to spell something out. It seems like the subtlety arises in the fact that letters are almost never mentioned.